# I have to validate that is end time greater then start time using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to validate that is end time greater then start time.
and my time formate 'HH:MM' ,24 hour formate

eg. start time = 09:14 and end time 12:15 - valid

and start time = 09:14 and end time 01:15 - not valid

thanks
have a nice day

I think a/c to this time it should be validate.i am little confused why are giving me this error **end time should be greater then start time.**

[image]

**jquery**

```
 $(document).change(function(){

  var startTime =$('#start_time').val(); // 9:15 Am
  var endTime = $('#end_time').val();    // 1:00 pm

    var startTimeParts = startTime.split(":");
    var endTimeParts = endTime.split(":");

    var startDate = new Date();
    startDate.setHours(startTimeParts[0],startTimeParts[1],0,0);
    var endDate = new Date();
    endDate.setHours(endTimeParts[0],endTimeParts[1],0,0);
    if(endTime != ""){
      if (startDate < endDate){
        $(".endTimeMessage").hide();
        $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr("disabled",true);
        return true;
    }else{
        $(".endTimeMessage").show();
        $(".endTimeMessage").text("End time should be greater then start time");
        $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
        return false;
    }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use setHours function to set the time and then compare the values.

eg.

```js
    $(document).change(function(){
        var startTime = "09:14";
        var endTime  =   "01:00";

        var startTimeParts = startTime.split(":");
        var endTimeParts = endTime.split(":");

        var startDate = new Date();
        startDate.setHours(startTimeParts[0],startTimeParts[1],0,0);
        var endDate = new Date();
        endDate.setHours(endTimeParts[0],endTimeParts[1],0,0);

        if (startDate > endDate){
            $(".endTimeMessage").hide();
            $(".endTimeMessage").text("End time should be greater then start time");
            $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr("disabled",true);
            return true;
        }else{
            $(".endTimeMessage").show();
            $(".endTimeMessage").text("End time should be greater then start time");
            $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you please explain how can i set start time and end time variable  inside setHours("09","14",0,0);  ? thank u.

Comment: please check my code i have updated

Comment: I have updated the answer assuming user is going to type time in hh:mm format